# how to integrate ckeditor and ckfinder with laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

I am very new to Laravel framework and I want to use CKEdiotor and ckfinder in Laravel5 but I don't know how to use it and how to install it. Anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it using composer.

Edit your *composer.json* file and add *"ckeditor/ckeditor":"dev-master"* in the *require* array

For ckfinder use *"jonlil/ckfinder":"dev-master"*

Then, run *composer install* and they will be automatically add in ypur vendors.

You can check for all available packages on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/)